# RPA Software for macOS

Tags: automation, macos

I'm currently an RPA developer using UiPath, I'm looking for a similar software to perform surface automation on a Mac running macOS Catalina (10.15.4).

I have tried Automator, however I am struggling to get it to click say links on a webpage, I can record it clicking them which sort of work but I want a little more control around what I'm telling/asking it to do.

At the minute everything I've seen is geared towards Windows users.